# What the downside could be when we define a function that never be used?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm learning JavaScript, yesterday I think I should revise some basic knowledge, so I chose "function" topic. When I read this document from  [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions), I saw this:

> Note: Some JavaScript engines, not including SpiderMonkey, incorrectly treat any function expression with a name as a function definition. This would lead to `zero` being defined, even with the always-false if condition. **A safer way** to define functions conditionally is to define the function anonymously and assign it to a variable:

```
if (0) {
    var zero = function() {
    document.writeln("This is zero.");
    }
}
```

So my question is, because it said **a safer way**, that's mean this way is not safe: What problem could be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a variable using `var` it's [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) to the top of the scope. So it would be possible for you to write some code like this:

```
if (someCondition) {
  var zero = function zero() {
    // do stuff
  };
}
if (zero) {
  zero();
}
```

When executed correctly, `zero` will always be `undefined` if `someCondition` is `false`.

If an engine incorrectly uses the named function expression as a function definition then it will be hoisted as well, meaning that `zero` will be a function *before `someCondition` is even checked.* This means that `zero` will have a "truthy" value no matter what `someCondition` is.

Basically, any time you would expect a value to be `undefined` because you haven't actually assigned a named function to it, it would actually be assigned to a function assuming you named that function the same thing as your variable.

Comment: There's nothing inaccurate here, but this answer is related to `var` scoping and not SpiderMonkey unsafely misinterpreting function expressions as declarations.

Comment: @DanPrince Not true. I added information about how function declarations are hoisted and therefore would create a defined value for `zero`.

Comment: I checked the hoisting document, and it said variable can be declared on the top of scope. Thanks @MikeC for useful link.